# how to use bullet physics game and ndk to develop 3d game in android device

Tags: android, android-ndk, physics-engine, bulletphysics

My homework is to do a 3d game which needs a physics engine support.  I chose a bullet, but  it was written in C++, and I proposed to build my project with ndk. However, to run a bullet program, you need four static library files:

- BulletCollision_debug.lib
- BulletDynamics_debug.lib
- BulletSoftBody_debug.lib
- LinearMath_debug.lib

I don't know how to deal with these libraries under ndk-build.  Besides that, I want to know the difference between .lib and .a.  The former is a c++ static library, and the latter is an ndk static library.  Could you help me clarify the puzzle?

Answer (score 1):

Those are different library formats the .lib is for windows I believe. You probably want to look into using the NDK for android.